# Add columns to export to Excel in Survey list

Tags: export, survey

The survey list is always left of centre to other lists.

I am using SharePoint 2007.

I have recently been asked to include other columns when exporting a survey to excel (the modified field).

The default view for survey lists is "Overview".

I have found a workaround to edit the web part on the Overview.aspx page (using edit page->Modify shared web part) to point to another view I had created (by manually pointing to ViewType.aspx), which includes the extra field.

Now I tested it and the extra columns are appearing in the export.
Great.

Is this the best way to do this? I don't want to risk breaking the survey functionality by modifying the view the web part is pointing to.

Thanks

Feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up Creating a new view, called "extra options" view - pointing directly to the Create view page.

Then, I created a spreadsheet (did an export as before), and updated the query Caml in the data connection.